# Get Tile Count of a Map View In android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, tiles, osmdroid

I have successfully integrated OSM (Open Street Maps) to my application and the map view is loading. There is a functionality to capture the screen. User should only be able capture when all tiles are loaded. But at the moment, even when tiles are not fully loaded, user can still capture the screen.

Is there a method to get current loaded tiles, or a boolean flag to check whether the map is fully loaded?

I found out the number of tiles that should be there with each zoom level:

Zoom level 0 is 1 tile. (1 x 1)

Zoom level 1 is 4 tiles. (2 x 2)

Zoom level 2 is 16 tiles. (4 x 4)

Zoom level 3 is 64 tiles. (8 x 8)

Zoom level 4 is 256 tiles (16 x 16) and so on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if the OSM Mapview is still loading or not in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079359/detect-if-the-osm-mapview-is-still-loading-or-not-in-android)