# Detect OSMDroid map loading completed

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Is there some way to detect when OSMDroid MapView have completed map loading ? I want to know, when OSMDroid ends drawing tiles and overlays on view.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking around for an answer to your question, and stumbled upon this other question:
[Detect if the OSM Mapview is still loading or not in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079359/detect-if-the-osm-mapview-is-still-loading-or-not-in-android)
A less heavy solution could be found probably, without having to define a new class just to check if the OSM MapView map has been loaded, but for now that question is probably what you're looking for.